# Ace editor getValue newline format?

Tags: javascript, python, ace-editor

Ace editor only accept \n and \" setting:
You can see setValue's content has \n and \" tag.

```
var editor1 = ace.edit("editor1");
editor1.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
editor1.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/python");
editor1.setFontSize(15);
editor1.setValue("def main():\n    # Your code goes here\n\nif __name__ == \"__main__\":\n    main()");
```

But when I use `editor1.getValue()`to get value from ace editor.
It will get non \n tag like below:

```
def main():
    # Your code goes here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But How to use non \n's value to editor1.setValue again.
I want to implement the function that can modify old code store in database.
The code will store `editor1.getValue()` into database.
So it will be wrong to 
editor1.setValue(

```
def main():
    # Your code goes here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

)

This is my project:https://github.com/easytrader/StrategyWebsite

How to solve this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: are you inserting value stored in database into html with php?

Comment: Yes,this is my project:https://github.com/easytrader/StrategyWebsite

Comment: I use python to store the code. But editor1.getValue() return code type doen't accept by editor1.setValue.